# Need help on algorithm homework which is a probability theory problem

Tags: probability, algorithms

I've got an algorithm homework and it looks like a pure probability problem, I currently got stuck on solving it. 
I'll rephrase it to an easier-to-understand problem and show where I am struggling.

The problem is like this:
There are balloons with three different colors **R**(red), **G**(green), **B**(blue). There are $n$ **R** and $n$ **G** ballons, the total number of ballons is unknown(strange...). Each ballon has probability $p$ to explode, then we collect those exploded balloons. If there is one **R** and zero **G** in this collection is said to be good. Now assume $p=\frac1n$, then prove that **P**(the collection is good)$>$some positive constant independent of $n$.
There is a hint says when $x,n$ are real numbers and $|x|<n$, the inequality below holds:

$$e^x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)\leq\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\leq e^x$$

What I want to do is to use the law of total probability, calculate
$$P(\text{good}|\text{collection size}=i)*P(\text{collection size}=i)$$ and sum up from $1$ to total number of ballons(unknown)
I assume total number of ballon is $U$ so when size$=1$
$$P(\text{good}|\text{size}=1)*P(\text{size}=1)=\frac{n}{U}*\binom{U}{1}\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{U-1}$$
size$=2$
$$P(\text{good}|\text{size}=2)*P(\text{size}=2)=\frac{n}{U}\frac{U-2n}{U-1}*\binom{U}{2}\frac{1}{n}^2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{U-2}$$ 
size$=i$
$$P(\text{good}|\text{size}=i)*P(\text{size}=i)=\frac{n}{U}\frac{U-2n}{U-1}\frac{U-2n-1}{U-2}...\frac{U-2n-i+2}{U-i+1}*\binom{U}{i}\frac{1}{n}^i\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{U-i}\\
=\frac{n(U-2n)(U-2n-1)...(U-2n-i+2)}{i!}\frac{1}{n}^i\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{U-i}$$

the range of $i$ will be from $1$ to $U-2n+1$ because the largest size of collection will contain all **B**, one **R** and zero **G**, otherwise it's not 'good'.
I tried to sum up those probabilities together:
$$P(\text{good})=\sum_{i=1}^{U-2n+1}P(\text{good}|\text{size}=i)*P(\text{size}=i)\\
=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{U-1}+\sum_{i=2}^{U-2n+1}P(\text{good}|\text{size}=i)*P(\text{size}=i)$$ 
then I have no idea how to compute this.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: So there are the same number of red as green balloons?

Comment: yes, they are the same